# display clickable Amazon image links from JAVA to HTML

Tags: javascript, html

have a simple calculation that if the selected 2 radio is true it will display the correct link to the div where you can find it. the link is now clickable and opens the right website/URL thanks to User: imvain2 who helped with some of the code. Now when I put an Amazon link in it, it only displays the URL and not the Amazon affiliate clickable Image link.

```
 <div id="DisplayResults"></div>

    function create_link(url, target_obj){
        var a = document.createElement('a');
        var linkText = document.createTextNode(url);
        a.appendChild(linkText);
        a.title = url;
        a.href = url;
        target_obj.appendChild(a);
    }

function Selectport() {

var aOpticalin = document.getElementById("aOpticalin");
var aOpticalout = document.getElementById("aOpticalout");
var astereoout = document.getElementById("astereoout");
var astereoin = document.getElementById("astereoin");
var DisplayResults = document.getElementById("DisplayResults");


    if(astereoout.checked && aOpticalin.checked){

create_link(<iframe style="width:120px;height:240px;" marginwidth="0" 
marginheight="0" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" src="//ws- 
na.amazon-adsystem.com/widgets/q? 
ServiceVersion=20070822&OneJS=1&Operation=GetAdHtml&MarketPlace= 
US&source=ac&ref= 
tf_til& ad_type=product_link&tracking_id=whatsmycable- 
20&marketplace=amazon&region=US&placement=B01HGHNCMW&asins= 
B01HGHNCMW&linkId= 
f3759832fc138a941ade9bde6128b083&show_border= 
true&link_opens_in_new_window= 
false&price_color=333333&title_color=000000&bg_color=d1d1d1">
</iframe>,DisplayResults);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That function was originally created based on simply creating a link from a URL. If you would like to append actual precreated HTML, you can use innerHTML.

Make sure to wrap your code in single quotes (apostrophes) if your code has double quotes in it.

```
DisplayResults.innerHTML += 'Your iframe code goes here';
```